# gwt - calling a static java method from outside javascript works but doesn't affect the gwt code

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

I have an embedded iframe in an HTML page.
The page in the iframe was created with GWT.

The GWT program has static variables, a static method that I exposed so it could be called from outside.
In The GWT program, there's a timer that checks the static variable every 10 seconds.

The outside HTML page has a button, and when the button is pressed, a javascript code calls the static method in my gwt program (that's in an iframe in the HTML)

I can see that the GWT static method is called (there's a js alert call inside).
But the function that runs every 10 seconds and check the static variable (that was changed in the static method) reports that its value hasn't changed.

HTML snippets

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/war/mygwtproject/mygwtproject.nocache.js">
<iframe id="feeds_frame" src="../root/war/mygwtproject.html" width="190" height="650" frameborder="1">

        </iframe>


function toggleDrawingFeeds()
        {
            myGwtStaticMethod();
        }
```

GWT Code

```
static boolean wasInitiated = false;

public static void myFunc()
{
    MyGwt.wasInitiated = true;
    alert(MyGwt.wasInitiated);
}

public void setTimer()
    {


        Timer t = new Timer()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                alert(MyGwt.wasInitiated);
                if (MyGwt.wasInitiated)
                {
                    //do something
                }
                else
                {
                    //do something else
                }
            }
        };


        // Schedule the timer to run once in 5 seconds.
        t.scheduleRepeating(10000);

    }


    public static native void exportStaticMethod() /*-{

    $wnd.myGwtStaticMethod = $entry(@myPackage.MyEntryPoint::myFunc());


}-*/;
```

Thanks,
Yoav

Comment: Are you getting alert at every 10 second ?

Comment: yes I am. but The value of the static variable remains the same.

Comment: Distinguish both alert(MyGwt.wasInitiated); to check values ?

Comment: yes, the first one is actually alert("init was called"+ MyGwt.wasInitiated);

Comment: the problem definition is very vague, please be more specific or include additional code snippets to further demonstrate your problem (what does `toggleDrawingFeeds()` has to do with anything? it's obviously not a part of the raw html).